# Laravel URL::route() not returning absolute path

Tags: laravel

- Laravel Version: 5.8.*
- PHP Version: 7.1.3
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL

#### Description:

When requesting

```
URL::route('test.index');
```

(or any route name), from the following page
http://app.test/sitemap.xml

the returned result is:
**https://test.app/sitemap.xml/test**

The desired output is 
**https://test.app/test**

Even though the absolute is set true (it is by default), by not including the third parameter.
I already tried explicitly setting it to true:

```
URL::route('test.index', [], true);
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Create a route to catch a visit to sitemap.xml, and return a (wrongly) generated route

```
Route::get('/sitemap.xml', function () {
     return \URL::route('test');
 });
```

This is the route definition of my test route

```
Route::get('test', function() {return 'test';})->name('test');
```

Comment: What's the value of `config('app.url')`?

Comment: And show us the route definition for the route named `test`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. This likely indicates an issue with the rewrite configuration.

Comment: Works as intended for me. Can you show us your routes with `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @ceejayoz the app url value in my .env is: APP_URL=http://app.test, but it doesn't seem to affect the url's i'm generating for some reason..

Comment: @BramVerstraten There's a lot of routes, what exactly are we looking for?